# IdFTP, upload directory and subdirectories

Tags: ftp, c++builder, indy

I need upload directory and subdirectories on server. I think i need to call method `IdFTP->Put(...);`
But I dont know how to do it. Help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
void PutDir(TIdFTP* AIdFTP, const String& AFrom)
{
    TSearchRec SR;
    if (FindFirst(AFrom+"\\*.*", faAnyFile, SR)== 0)
    {
        do
        {
            if(SR.Name!= "." && SR.Name!= "..")
            {
                if (SR.Attr & faDirectory)
                {
                    AIdFTP->MakeDir(SR.Name);
                    AIdFTP->ChangeDir(SR.Name);
                    PutDir(AIdFTP,AFrom+"\\"+SR.Name);
                    AIdFTP->ChangeDirUp();
                }
                else
                {
                    AIdFTP->Put(AFrom+"\\"+SR.Name,SR.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        while (FindNext(SR)== 0);

        FindClose(SR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`TIdFTP::Put()` uploads a single file.  `TIdFTP` does not natively support uploading folders, so you will have to implement it manually:

1. use `TIdFTP::ChangeDir()` to go to the starting parent folder.
2. use `TIdFTP::Put()` to upload each file into that folder.
3. use `TIdFTP.MakeDir()` to create each subfolder in that folder.
4. recursively repeat #1 for each subfolder that you created in #3.